# Using TensorFlow's TFRecordReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a `tfrecords` file and want to view the contents of the file using tensorflow's `TFRecordReader`. I want to display the contents of the file in the command prompt but haven't gotten anywhere. Any directions would help

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for information on how to use the TFRecordReader class, this example has some code that uses it:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py
which is linked from
https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/
. The reference documentation is here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/io_ops/readers
.

If you just want to view the contents of a TFRecord file as bytes, the tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator class should do what you want. It is defined here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py

Here's an example of code that uses it:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/gcs_test/python/gcs_smoke.py

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at -  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960319/tensorflow-taking-too-long-to-read-a-tfrecord-file)