# Tensorflow taking too long to read a tfrecord file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tfrecord file that has five columns - context, context_len, utterance, uuterance_len and label. The [source of the tfrecord file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_bZck-ksdkpVEtVc1R6Y01HMWM) is the Ubuntu Dialog Corpus. Problem is that its taking way too long to read in the file

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['data/samples/train.tfrecords'], num_epochs = 1)

reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, 
features = {
"context" : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
"context_len" : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
"utterance" : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
"utterance_len" : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
"label" : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
})

contexts = features['context']
context_lens = features['context_len']
utterances = features['utterance']
utterance_lens = features['utterance_len']
labels = features['label']

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
sess.run(contexts)
```

When the code took too long to read the file, I thought it must be due to the file size. So I subsetted the original csv file down to ten records and converted it into a tfrecords file but no difference. I'm still facing the same issue. So now I'm convinced it has something to do with my code. My objective is to parse a single example and use it later to train a RNN.

Comment: you need to start queue runners before the first run call

Comment: This helped. The code's running now. Can you put it in an answer. Will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to start queue runners before the first run call

Comment: How do you start the queue runners? Would be a great addition to this answer,... thanks!

Comment: tf.start_queue_runners()